# New beta theme has odd migration direction indicators

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, migration

With the new beta theme, I noticed that the migration direction indicators on `/tools?tab=migrated` and `admin/posts/migrated/here` are a little odd:

[image]

Compare to the indicators for migrations *away* from the site:

[image]

At first I though the new indicators could be used to show that the migration was rejected, but that doesn't seem to be the case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Jin pushed a fix earlier today. Should be live in the next build. Thanks!